# JavaFX update textArea

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-2, javafx

I have a simple JavaFX application which has a TextArea. I can update the content of the textArea with the code below inside the start() method:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) { 

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    txtarea.appendText("text\n");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}).start();
```

The code just write the `text` string into the TextArea 2000 times. I want to update this textArea from a function which is implemented outside of the start() method.

```
public void appendText(String p){
    txtarea.appendText(p);
}
```

This function can be called from arbitrary programs which use the JavaFX application to update the TextArea. How can I do this inside the appendText function?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What are you trying to achieve? What prevents you from calling your method?

Comment: If I call the appendText method in a for cycle, for example:

for(int i=0; i<5000; i++)
class.appendText("Test");

I get the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGTextHelper$TextAttributes.computeLinePadding(NGTextHelper.java:389)

Comment: can you show a short example that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could give the class which needs to write to the `javafx.scene.control.TextArea` an reference to your class which holds the `public void appendText(String p)` method and then just call it. I would suggest you also pass an indication from which class the method was called, e.g.:

```
public class MainClass implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private TextArea txtLoggingWindow;
    [...more code here...]
    public void appendText(String string, String string2) {
       txtLoggingWindow.appendText("[" + string + "] - " + string2 + "\n");
    }
}

public class SecondClass {
    private MainClass main;
    public SecondClass(MainClass mClass) {
        this.main = mClass;
    }
    public void callMainAndWriteToArea() {
        this.main.appendText(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), "This Text Goes To TextArea");
    }
}
```